# 2d C array isn't printing or is creating incorrectly

Tags: arrays, c, gcc, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I wrote a piece of c code to create a 2d array and then print it. However it doesn't print and I can see that each loop seems to be running for the correct time.

I'm very new to c so this answer might be really basic sorry.

my code compiles fine (gcc) but then doesn't return what I expect. im using ubuntu 18.04 in WSL with gcc as my compiler.

heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, k;

    int array[2][3] = {0};

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("l1 ");
        for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            scanf("%d", &array[i][k]);
            printf("l2 ");
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        printf("l3 ");
        printf("%d ",  array[k][i]);

        if(i == 2) {
                i = -1;
                ++k;
                printf("\n");
        }
        if(k == 3) {
                printf("yay");
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

the terminal window looks like this:

```
l1 1
l2 2
l2 3
l2 l1 4
l2 5
l2 6
l2 l3 32602 yay
```

the numbers are the elements im entering apart from the final one which seems to be coming out as the output however it is nothing like what i would expect it to be.

i would expect it to print all my array elements but i dont understand why it doesnt since i dont get an error in gcc so my syntax seems fine.

Thanks.

Comment: `if(k == 3)` What value do you expect `k` to hold after this loop `for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)`?

Comment: "so my syntax seems fine." Syntax errors are only the easiest errors. Your compiler even tells you about them. All other errors are harder to find.

Comment: General hint: For such tiny programs the very first step would be to run it in a debugger and step through your instructions while watching the variables involved. This should immediately show you where you come along in the second loop and what value `k` holds.

Comment: i know that syntax errors are only the simplest however i was simply writing that so that people would know that my compiler didn't see a syntax error so that probably wasn't an issue.

Comment: how would i run it through a debugger?

Comment: I like the approach but I think it's over complicating the task, first of all as @Gerhardh noted, you're reusing `k` right after the second loop ends, you should take a second back and think about what the value of `k` might be.
I'd try to approach the problem using the most intuitive solution, that way I don't have to deal with such nuances!

Comment: ok thanks ill do some googling and get right on debugging!

Comment: @Newbie you don't need to tell us there are no syntax errors, because if there where syntax errors you would have shown us the error log of the compiler, wouldn't you?

Comment: i have just tried to debug it and am confused as to how the gdb debugger works. i cant manage to get it to step through instructions instead it seems to simply run all of them at once. i am doing ``` gcc -ggdb ``` and then ``` gdb a.out```

Comment: @Newbie great opportunity to learn, there are certainly plenty of tutorials

Comment: after a significant amount of time for debugging i still cannot fix the issue, does anyone know what the error is so they can explain it to me?

Comment: Do you actually read the comments? My first comment already points out that something is wrong with `k`. Also Cufox wrote it in comment. Sidenote: In bug hunting, ~90 minutes are not a significant amount of time. Especially when learning basic programming techniques is involved.

Comment: Ok, please step away from the screen and try to explain to your [rubber duck](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) why is your code scanning all those `array[i][k]` (note the order of the indices) values (without checking the value returned by `scanf`) in a nice nested loop and then, not only it doesn't use the same nested loop, but also prints `array[k][i]`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to install ddd (a display debugger, internally it uses gdb by default).  do

```
sudo apt install ddd
```

Now, do

```
gcc -g test.c
```

now you get a.out. (if you do `gcc -g test.c -o test`, you'll get `test` as executable)

and run the debugger.

```
ddd a.out
```

now you'll see the source code window and a command window.  In the command window, type `b main` (break at main). The a.out runs and stops at main. (you know there stuffs running before main.) press 'n' for next (run till next line), to enter into a function press `s` (step-in), to finish a function from inside, press `f`, to run until line 100, `u 100`, etc. Search about gdb commands. To display a variable in a separate graphic window, do `graph disp i`. To set a break at line 100, `b 100`, to set break in line 100 if j == 3, `b 100 if j == 3`. To print a value i, `p i`, There is watch command (you run it, when the watched value changes, it stops). etc.
I don't know what you are trying to do, but didn't you forget settkgin k=0 between the two big for loops? Anyway, you could do debugging and find where it's wrong.
ADD : If you would like to use plain gdb, after entering type `layout src` and you'll the source code. The remaning commands are the same except graphic display.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int i, k;

    int array[2][3] = {0};

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("l1 ");
        for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            scanf("%d", &array[i][k]);
            printf("l2 ");
        }
    }
```

Consider this loop, it will leave 'k' at k=3 after finish, and then if you do this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        printf("l3 ");
        printf("%d ",  array[k][i]); // exactly here

        if(i == 2) {
                i = -1;
                ++k;
                printf("\n");
        }
        if(k == 3) {
                printf("yay");
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

You will try to access arr[3][0] which is out of bounds, that's why 32602 is printed,
And as you progress further with k=3 and(still) i=0, you get to if(k==3) condition, which prints `yay`, returns 0 and ends the process.

Comment: But adding something as `k=0` in between two loops will not solve the problem, as you will keep incrementing this k up to number 3 until the loop stops, and it will still try to print array[2][x]